# SQL Get Users By One Group But Exclude Others

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query that retrieves all users that belong to group `A`, but excludes users that belong groups `B`, `C` & `D`.

Users are uniquely identified by `user_id` in the `users` table, but can have multiple entries in the `groups` table.

I have the following query but it's not working:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN groups USING (user_id)
WHERE groups.name = 'A'
AND groups.name NOT IN ('B', 'C', 'D')
```

This just selects all users from group `A`.

How include anyone from group `A` but exclude them if they are in groups `B`,`C` & `D`?

Comment: What does the data in `groups.name` look llike? Is that a delimited list like `A,B`?

Comment: No it's just a varchar. In this case either `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` for the case of group name `A` and `NOT EXISTS` for the case of group names `B, C, D`:

```
select distinct user_id
from groups g
where 
  exists (
    select 1 from groups where user_id = g.user_id and name = 'A'
  )
  and not exists (
    select 1 from groups where user_id = g.user_id and name in ('B', 'C', 'D')
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM groups
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(g.name = 'A') > 0 AND
       SUM(g.name IN ('B', 'C', 'D')) = 0;
```

Note:  You don't need to join to `users`.  Your query is only selecting the user id, which is in the `groups` table.  Of course, if you need additional columns from `users` you can join to it (or use `in` or `exists`).

Comment: Could you add an example for the join as well?

Comment: @Dangerman1988 . . . This answers the question that you asked.  It should be pretty clear how to add a `join` to the query.

Answer (score 1):

use exists

```
    select t1.user_id from users t1
    where exists( select 1 from groups t2 where t1.user_id=t2.user_id
                   and t2.name='A')
   and not exists( select 1 from groups t2 where t1.user_id=t2.user_id
                        and t2.name NOT IN ('B', 'C', 'D') )
```

Comment: It's the other way around, I want to exclude them if they belong to any of B,C or D